# Free char pointer in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I am trying to find out filetypes using c code, here is the code

```
char *get_file_type(char *path, char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char command[100];
    char file_details[100];
    char *filetype;

    sprintf(command, "file -i %s%s", path, filename);
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(file_details,  sizeof(file_details)-1, fp) != NULL) {
         filetype = (strtok(strstr(file_details, " "), ";"));
    }

    pclose(fp);
    return filetype;
}
```

here instead of declaring command[], can I use *command? I tried to use it, but it throwed an exception. we dont need to free up variables declared like command[]? if yes how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `char *command;`, but then, you must allocate some memory for `command`to refer to with a call to `malloc()` and when you are done ith that memory, it has to be freed again with a call to `free()`.

As you can see, that is a lot more work than using a fixed-size array (as you do now), but it can be made a lot safer as well, because you could create a buffer of exactly the right size, instead of hoping that the total length of the command won't exceed 100 characters.

Aside from that, your code has a problem: The `filetype` pointer that the function returns points to a location within the array `file_details`, but that array will be cleaned up by the compiler when executing the `return` statement, so the pointer that gets returned by the function refers to some memory that is marked as "free to be used for other purposes".

If it is not a problem that the result of `get_file_type` is only valid for one file at a time, you can declare the `file_details` array as `static`, so that it will be preserved across calls to the function.

Comment: You can, but then you must remember to call `free` in the calling function(s) to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 15):

When you declare an array:

```
char command[100];
```

the compiler allocates the memory for it (100 chars in this case) and `command` points to the start of that memory.  You can access the memory you've allocated:

```
command[0]  = 'a';  // OK
command[99] = 'A';  // OK
command[100] = 'Z'; // Error: out of bounds
```

but you cannot change the value of `command`:

```
command = NULL;     // Compile-time error
```

The memory will be automatically freed when `command` goes out of scope.

---

When you declare a pointer:

```
char *commandptr;
```

you only create a single variable for pointing to `char`s, but it doesn't point to anything yet.  Trying to use it without initialising it is an error:

```
commandptr[0] = 'A';   // Undefined behaviour; probably a segfault
```

You need to allocate the memory yourself using `malloc`:

```
commandptr = malloc(100);
if (commandptr) {
    // Always check that the return value of malloc() is not NULL
    commandptr[0] = 'A';  // Now you can use the allocated memory
}
```

and free it when you've finished with it:

```
free(commandptr);
```

Comment: Actually, stack array do not get freed, because it do not need to.
To be totally honest, malloc and free are syscalls(well, wrappers to them), while stack array are not.

Comment: @KAction 'malloc' allocates memory in heap !

Answer (score 1):

Why would you change it? For temporary buffers, people usually declare the arrays with [] so they don't have to worry about garbage disposal.

Comment: but can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: For one thing, it probably would make sense to dynamically allocate a buffer based on the lengths of `path` and `filename` rather than silently allowing a buffer overflow. (C99 variable length arrays would solve this, though.  Using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` would be advisable too.)